# Pyechonest Installation

Tags: python, module

I am very new to Python. The first task I was given is to install and run [Pyechonest](https://github.com/echonest/pyechonest) (a Python API to [The Echo Nest](http://the.echonest.com/)) to its full effect.  The Pyechonest readme instructs me to:

- Use setuptools: `easy_install -U pyechonest`
- Download the zipfile from the [releases](https://github.com/echonest/pyechonest/releases) page and install it.
- Checkout the source: `git clone git://github.com/echonest/pyechonest.git` and install it yourself.

I need somebody to step me through the process of configuring my Windows system to the point where I can run this installer.  This is all new to me.

I will be very grateful if you could help me somehow. Been on it for three days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain the easy_install way, as this will be the easiest for a beginner (like myself), also for modules you'll be wanting to install in the future:

1) get the ez_setup.py file from: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py and save it at some easy place (let's say: "C:\Users\You\Downloads\ez_setup.py").

2) run that file - I believe you can just double-click it - but I usually run it in command line: open cmd (command prompt) and type the following (directory names may vary depending on your system, but you'll get the point):

```
C:\Python27\python C:\Users\You\Downloads\ez_setup.py
```

3) Now you have installed setuptools, and so you now have access to easy_install. To install modules you can now do the following:

```
C:\Python27\Scrips\easy_install.exe pyechonest
```

Note: "Python27" can vary depending on your version, change pyechonest with any other module's name supported by easy_install.
To all pro's out there, I'm quite a noob myself, so feel free to correct me. I assumed you didn't have anything added to PATH variables, so I used full paths.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you!
I did manage to solved this problem. Anyway, if anyone finds it difficult, your answer will most certainly help them.